# hp probook 455 g1 screen flickering and showing strange colors

Tags: laptop, lid

I have hp probook 455 g1 laptop for 10 months and few days ago screen started to display strange colors and flickering. This especially happens when I move the lid or change it's position. It stops to flicker if the lid is below 70 degrees, sometimes it stops flickering when I find a position at about 100 degrees. After 100 degrees it flickers much harder, and after about 130 degrees the screen completely changes to darker color. In addition if you
position the lid that it won't flicker and click under the screen, about at the place where the lid is connected to the body, the screen begins to flicker and change colors, after you release it stops. Do anyone know what can this could cause? How can I fix it? I'm almost sure it's hardware related because this happens always, even in bios settings and during boot.
See images

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWNDW.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eHKp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a cable to your laptop's screen got too close to the edge of the hinge between the screen and the bottom part of the laptop and got pinched or a cable has a bad electrical connection. Maybe you need to firmly reconnect or replace the cable. Shut down your laptop, and connect a second monitor to your laptop in order to check if there's anything visually wrong with the output to the second monitor.

I've noticed the same pattern that is shown graphically in your screenshots happen when using headphones. There is a constant low volume static noise accompanying the normal audio output to one side of the headphones. Pushing the cable on the side of the headphones with the static a little bit closer against the headphone speaker eliminates the static noise, which apparently is being caused by a bad electrical connection between the cable and one side of the headphones. When I move the cable again, the static noise resumes.